# Make a list / table with 2 FOR in Python

Tags: python

I made a program and it was like that at the exit

```
A       Alanina
B       Ácido aspártico ou Asparagina
C       Cisteína
D       Ácido aspártico
E       Ácido glutâmico
F       Fenilalanina
G       Glicina
H       Histidina
I       Isoleucina
J       Leucina (L) ou Isoleucina
K       Lisina
L       Leucina
M       Metionina
N       Asparagina
O       Pirrolisina
P       Prolina
Q       Glutamina
R       Arginina
S       Serina
T       Treonina
U       Selenocisteína
V       Valina
W       Triptofano
X       qualquer
Y       Tirosina
33
0
4
26
32
14
38
14
26
0
25
36
15
16
0
19
15
16
14
20
0
32
0
11
```

But I want these numbers to be next to the letter and word column, a list where the type would look like

-A ------ Alanina -------- number of times the A appears

-B ------ Aspartic acid or asparagine -------- number of times B appears

it is getting information from an e.coli.fasta.txt file:

```
>sp|A1AA21|PEPT_ECOK1 Peptidase T OS=Escherichia coli O1:K1 / APEC OX=405955 GN=pepT PE=3 SV=1
MDKLLERFLNYVSLDTQSKAGVRQVPSTEGQWKLLHLLKEQLEEMGLINVTLSEKGTLMA
TLPANVPGDIPAIGFISHVDTSPDCSGKNVNPQIVENYRGGDIALGIGDEVLSPVMFPVL
HQLLGQTLITTDGKTLLGADDKAGIAEIMTALAVLQQKNIPHGDIRVAFTPDEEVGKGAK
HFDVDAFDARWAYTVDGGGVGELEFENFNAASVNIKIVGNNVHPGTAKGVMVNALSLAAR
IHAEVPADESPEMTEGYEGFYHLASMKGTVERADMHYIIRDFDRKQFEARKRKMMEIAKK
VGKGLHPDCYIELVIEDSYYNMREKVVEHPHILDIAQQAMRDCDIEPELKPIRGGTDGAQ
LSFMGLPCPNLFTGGYNYHGKHEFVTLEGMEKAVQVIVRIAELTAQRK
```

and this is the program code:

```
f = open('e.coli.fasta.txt','r')
sequencia = f.readlines()
amino = [] #para colocar o arquivo numa lista só com o texto de interresse 

for linha in sequencia:
  if linha.find('>') != 0:
    amino.append(linha)

tfasta= "".join(amino)

aminoacidos = {}
aminoacidos = {'A':'Alanina','B':'Ácido aspártico ou Asparagina','C':'Cisteína', 'D':'Ácido aspártico','E':'Ácido glutâmico','F':'Fenilalanina','G':'Glicina','H':'Histidina','I':'Isoleucina','J':'Leucina (L) ou Isoleucina','K':'Lisina','L':'Leucina','M':'Metionina','N':'Asparagina','O':'Pirrolisina','P':'Prolina','Q':'Glutamina','R':'Arginina','S':'Serina','T':'Treonina','U':'Selenocisteína','V':'Valina','W':'Triptofano','X':'qualquer','Y':'Tirosina'}

def ocorrencias(string):
  result = {}
  chaves = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXY'
  for i in chaves:
    result[i] = tfasta.count(i)
  return result  

ocor = (ocorrencias(tfasta))

with open ('PeptidadeT-aminoacidos','w') as p:
  for i in range(65,90):
    a = ('%s' % (chr(i)))
    p.write('{:4s}\t{:5s}\n'.format(a,(aminoacidos[a])))
  for e in ocor.values():
    p.write('{}\n'.format(e))
```

Comment: Can you post in English?

Comment: I just posted in English

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Have you done any debugging? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `ocor` is a python data type called dictionary[1]. In your code it is compose of {key: value} = {"aminoacido": ocorrencias}. You can use aminoacid name to get the number of occurencies just like this: `ocor['A']` it will return 33.

```
f = open('e.coli.fasta.txt','r')
sequencia = f.readlines()
amino = [] #para colocar o arquivo numa lista só com o texto de interresse 

for linha in sequencia:
  if linha.find('>') != 0:
    amino.append(linha)

tfasta= "".join(amino)

aminoacidos = {}
aminoacidos = {'A':'Alanina','B':'Ácido aspártico ou Asparagina','C':'Cisteína', 'D':'Ácido aspártico','E':'Ácido glutâmico','F':'Fenilalanina','G':'Glicina','H':'Histidina','I':'Isoleucina','J':'Leucina (L) ou Isoleucina','K':'Lisina','L':'Leucina','M':'Metionina','N':'Asparagina','O':'Pirrolisina','P':'Prolina','Q':'Glutamina','R':'Arginina','S':'Serina','T':'Treonina','U':'Selenocisteína','V':'Valina','W':'Triptofano','X':'qualquer','Y':'Tirosina'}

def ocorrencias(string):
  result = {}
  chaves = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY'
  for i in chaves:
    result[i] = tfasta.count(i)
  return result

ocor = ocorrencias(tfasta)

with open ('PeptidadeT-aminoacidos','w') as p:
  for i in range(65,90):
    a = ('%s' % (chr(i)))
    p.write('-{:4s}------{:5s}------{}\n'.format(a, aminoacidos[a], ocor[a]))
```

Just a side note here: it was missing the letter W on `chaves`, I just added it to prevent `KeyError`. If this is not wanted,  you can add try/except clause on p.write.

```
chaves = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY'
```

[1] https://realpython.com/python-dicts/